# How to update existing cms page through install script

Tags: magento-1.8, setup-script

I have this script

```
<?php
$cmsPage = Array ( 

                    'title' => 'Test Page 1',
                    'root_template' => 'one_column', 
                    'identifier' => 'testpage1', 
                    'content' => "<p>Testowa sprawa czy działa update ? oooooooooooo</p>", 
                    'is_active' => 1,
                    'stores' => array(1), 
                    'sort_order' => 0 
    );


Mage::getModel('cms/page')->setData($cmsPage)->save();
```

If cms page with identifier "testpage1" exist , the script create another with the same identifier.

Is there a way to check if cmspage exist - and if that is true - do update ?

Answer (score 2):

I came accross the exact same problem on Magento 1.9.2.2

I couldn't find why, but every time I wanted to update a specific cms page, it was creating a new one instead. I finally checked the controller code, and after seeing it was the same code I was using, I checked the data sent in the form. And the answer is the **page_id**.

Try setting the **page_id** of your current page in the data, and it should work.

```
$page = Mage::getModel('cms/page')
    ->load($identifier, 'identifier');

$pageData = array(
    'title' => 'Test Page 1',
    'root_template' => 'one_column',
    'identifier' => 'testpage1',
    'stores' => array(0),
    'content' => $content,
    'layout_update_xml' => $design,
    'page_id' => $page->getId()
);

$page->setData($pageData)
    ->save();
```

Comment: Seems like your answer is right, why  it is not accepted

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the store in order to update a page.

Load the page like this:

```
$pageToModify = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->setStores($storeId)->load($existingPageId);

$pageToModify->addData(array($attributeCode => $value));
```

Comment: In the setup script you most likely don't know the store before loading a model.

Comment: Yes, in that case you have to search for it before updating it and then update it or create it. Like here: https://github.com/monsieurbiz/Mbiz_Setup/blob/master/src/app/code/community/Mbiz/Setup/Model/Cms.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$cmsPage = Array ( 
    'title' => 'Test Page 1',
    'root_template' => 'one_column', 
    'identifier' => 'testpage1', 
    'content' => "<p>Testowa sprawa czy działa update ? oooooooooooo</p>", 
    'is_active' => 1,
    'stores' => array(1), 
    'sort_order' => 0 
);
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('identifier', 'testpage1');
$page = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($collection->getFirstItem()->getId());
$page->setData($cmsPage)->save();
```

Comment: Still the same. Creating new cms page

Comment: @MarekBadura. I've updated the answer. try this new approach.

Comment: Still the same - it creating new cms page

Comment: I made something like this:

$page = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load('testpage1','identifier');
if ($page->getId()) {
$page->setData($cmsPage)->save();
}


and it still creating new one

Comment: When i made this:

$page = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load('testpage1','identifier');
if ($page->getId()) {

} else { 
     $page->setData($cmsPage)->save();
}

It does nothing - so this save() action make new one

Comment: Make sure you are using the right identifier

Comment: Yes it is the same

Answer (score -1):

You need to do addData();
like:

```
$cmsPage = Array ( 

                    'title' => 'Test Page 1',
                    'root_template' => 'one_column', 
                    'identifier' => 'testpage1', 
                    'content' => "<p>Testowa sprawa czy działa update ? oooooooooooo</p>", 
                    'is_active' => 1,
                    'stores' => array(1), 
                    'sort_order' => 0 
    );


$page = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load('testpage1', 'identifier');

$page->addData($cmsPage)
        ->setStores(array(0))
        ->save();
```